# Finding rows with a # of consecutive rows set to zero. (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with ~2 million rows that has been processed over time (100 at a time), and marks each with a 1 in the active column based on findings.

Now that the processing is complete, I'd like to determine a way to look through that data and find any large batches where that column is set to 0 still (indicates a failure at some point in the processing).

I have an `id` column which is sequential 1 to 2 million, and the odds of the active column being set to 0 or 1 is about 50/50 (so, any batches of say 100+ zeroes would certainly be an anomaly).

Goal is to be able to have it point out to me:  'Hey, there's a batch of 2000 records in a row starting at id=500000, with the active column set to 0'.  Since looking through it manually will be virtually impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use variables for this purpose:

```
select grp, min(id), max(id), active, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (@grp := if(@a = active, @grp,
                         if(@a := active, @grp + 1, @grp + 1)
                        )
            ) as grp
      from t cross join
           (select @z := -1, @grp := 0) params
      order by id
     ) t
where active = 0
group by grp, active
order by count(*) desc;
```